# Create a List<Y> from a List<X> using Stream()

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-stream

I'm trying to create a `List<Y>` from a `List<X>`.
Here is my two classes :

```
public class X {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
    //Getters, setters
}

public class Y {
        private String a;
        private String b;
        //Getters, setters
   }
```

With forEach, it would be something like :

```
List<X> listX = getListX();
List<Y> listY = new ArrayList<>();
listX.forEach( x -> {
     Y object_y = new Y();
     object_y.set_a(x.get_a());
     object_y.set_b(x.get_b());
     listY.add(object_y);
});
```

Is there any other way to peform the same action using Stream() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `map` function for that:

```java
List<X> listX = getListX();
List<Y> listY = listX.stream().map( x -> {
     Y object_y = new Y();
     object_y.set_a(x.get_a());
     object_y.set_b(x.get_b());
     return object_y;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```